# Getting the value that fired the Oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Am very new to Oracle triggers. Suppose I have a trigger on an insert in the table emp. Is there a way to find out what was the inserted record that fired the trigger. I wanted the trigger to have code that does something if the inserted record was a particular value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you have a row-level trigger, you can simply use the `:NEW` pseudo-record

```
CREATE TRIGGER name_of_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT ON emp
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  <<declare variables>>
BEGIN
  IF( :new.ename = 'JUSTIN' )
  THEN
    <<do something if the newly inserted ENAME value is 'JUSTIN'>>
  END IF;
END;
```

For a DDL trigger, the approach is completely different.  In that case, the pseudofunctions ora_dict_obj_owner and ora_dict_obj_name will return the owner and name of the table that the DDL statement is operating on.

Comment: Hey @Justin Cave sorry to bother you but I realized I actually need a DDL or SYstem trigger and not a DML trigger. I would call a trigger everytime a new table gets created in the schema `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER drop_trigger AFTER CREATE ON hr.SCHEMA BEGIN END;` How will I get the name of the table created that fired the trigger now? Is it still NEW?

Comment: @Eosphorus - No, DDL triggers are very different animals.  Updated my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot Justin. This is quite a few times you have helped me out now. I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 7):

The row that is being insertes is available as `NEW` in the trigger

Check out the manual for more details.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#BABEBAAB

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955